# Tomcat 6 MySQL -> strange connection error

Tags: mysql, tomcat

I have an Ubuntu Server with Apache -> mod_jk -> Tomcat 6 -> MySQL. Everytime Tomcat loads a new *.war or it is restarted, it gives me this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
```

And now the strange thing: sometimes after some time (sometimes minutes or hours) and doing nothing, the applications works like a charm - without any other errors.

The connection is set up with tomcat itself (with this context-container) and goes up with 127.0.0.1
Also there is no problem with phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

Remy,
This issue unfortunately does not have a "simple" answer, as it varies on many things.  The error you are receiving is a general communication error that tomcat hands back signifying a communication issue, without being verbose about what the issue is.

To start with, I would suggest checking that your mysql is listening on 127.0.0.1, not simply localhost.  The reasoning for the differentiation is that servers that have ipv6 (even if it is just a local ::1) will try to prefer this connection first.

If you do a netstat -an | grep LISTEN, you should see port 3306.  What is that socket listening on?  Make sure that this matches up with what you are specifying in your tomcat settings and proceed from there.